# Are two IPs with different subnet masks but same netword IDs on the same network?

Tags: networking, subnet

I can't figure this out. I have two IPs, and two subnet masks:

```
IP1: 10.150.1.4   SM: 255.255.255.248
IP2: 10.150.1.6   SM: 255.255.255.224
```

These two hosts both have the same Network ID (10.150.1.0) but have different subnet masks. Are they in the same network?

Answer (score 3):

They are 50% in the same network :) IP1 can access hosts 10.150.1.1-10.150.1.6 directly, and IP2 can access hosts 10.150.1.1-10.150.1.30 directly.

IP1 cannot access host 10.150.1.7 at all, because it is the broadcast address for that network.

In practice, this kind of configuration doesn't work, and one of the host's netmasks must be fixed to match the real network configuration in the network gateway.

Comment: IOW, the `/29` is a subnet of the `/27`.